# Wiring Pool Subpanel for Pump and Receptacles

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel, pool

The project is to wire a sub-panel and three pool circuits. My 400A main panels (2) are about 35' away, and I don't have room inside the basement to mount the sub panel inside. I plan to use an Intermatic PE20000 60A outdoor load center (or a fancier PE25065RC that includes remote controls), and I will mount this on the outside of the house about 40' from the main panels. The load center will have three circuits to feed a 1.65HP 230V variable speed pump and two (2) 15A receptacle circuits (lighting & convenience).

Misc:

- Location is Virginia
- 14'x33' fiberglass in-ground pool located ~40' from house and sub-panel
- Hayward SP2303VSP pump (230v variable speed)
- No heater or other powered equipment
- Lighting circuit will supply (2) 12v transformers for (2) LED pool lights
- Convenience receptacle is required within 20' of the pool edge

I would appreciate any guidance on the following:

Main panel:

- 30A 2-pole GFCI

Sub panel (Intermatic PE20000):

- 15A 2-pole breaker (non GFCI) (pump)
- 15A 1-pole (non GFCI) (lighting recept)
- 15A 1-pole (non GFCI) (convenience recept)
- Non-bonded neutral and ground
- No additional ground rod

Wire from main to sub:

- (4) #10 THWN-2 copper stranded (~40' runs)

Wire from sub to circuits:

- (3) 12' #10 THWN-2 copper stranded from sub panel to 230v pump (L1, L2, ground) in watertight conduit (#10 to future proof the wire)
- (3) 60' #14 THWN-2 copper stranded from sub panel to 120v lighting receptacle (L, N, ground) via 3/4 schedule 80 PVC
- (3) 100' #14 THWN-2 copper stranded from sub panel to 120v convenience receptacle (L, N, ground) via 3/4 schedule 80 PVC
- All 3/4" schedule 80 conduit buried at 18"

Equipotential bonding: ~300' of #8 THWN-2 copper solid (bare) with equipotential connections to:

- 3' horizontal under pool coping/pavers around pool perimeter
- deep end stainless steel ladder anchor plate
- 230v pump ground (it's not double-insulated)
- bonding electrode within PVC at pool filter
- not bonded back to the sub panel

Specific questions:

- Is the #14 THWN-2 feed from sub panel to 230v pump sufficient (10FLA)? Consensus is yes per the pump manual
- Are the #14 THWN-2 20A circuit feeds sufficient for those lengths (90 deg THWN-2 #14 copper should be 25A)? Consensus is yes
- Does my #8 solid equipotential ground need to connect back to the sub-panel, or is the connection at the pump sufficient to tie back to the main ground? Not back to the subpanel - just to the pump.

Any recommendations for making things cleaner?

Comment: Is the idea of paralleling from the main panel just something you came up with on your own?  Given that many wires, why not just throw one more neutral in there, and skip the subpanel altogether?

Comment: Are you using #14 or #12 from the 20A breaker to the pump? Your mid-post says one and your endpost says the other.

Comment: I get the impression you might be a bit confused about how a subpanel works.  You don't need wires for every circuit you plan to put in your subpanel all the way back to your main panel (if you did, there would be no point in having a subpanel in the first place).  Instead, you use larger feeder wires to supply power to the subpanel, and those split off to individual circuits through the subpanel's breakers.  I'd highly recommend reading up more about how subpanels are generally wired before you start this project.

Comment: I wired a sub-panel in a previous house that had a main disconnect in the sub-panel, but I guess I was confused about how to wire one when there is no main disconnect. Sounds like I maybe I need something like a 60A breaker in the main, maybe #6? L1, L2, N and ground to sub-panel, and then do as I had planned from there with the three breakers in the sub-panel?

Comment: Harper - I meant #14 but crossed it with the 12' run. I was planning on #14 THWN-2 stranded copper from the sub-panel to the pump.     Also I see what you mean based on your first post about skipping the sub-panel. I was confused about it as Nate stated.

Comment: For the pump, I recommend pre-assembled liquid tight flexible conduit, instead of the rigid you have listed. This gives you flexibility to remove the motor pump from the pump assembly without having to disassemble the water lines or the conduit. Your pool supply store probably has these in stock, with the wire.

Comment: Note that for your pump, you will also need a disconnect within 5 feet of your pool.  This can be the circuit breaker itself if you mount it there, otherwise you'll need to add an additional disconnect.  This is required by your pump's labeling.

Comment: What were you planning to run the feeder wires to the subpanel *in*? THWN-2 isn't rated for direct burial...

Comment: TPE:  the feeder wires from the main to the sub-panel will not be in anything; they'll be routed inside the basement. The wires from the subpanel to the outlets will be in 3/4 schedule 80 pvc buried 18" deep. Do you guys recommend direct-burial cable vs THWN-2 in PVC?

Comment: Nate: your feedback here might be the most concerning yet. "A disconnecting means located at least 5 ft. from the inside wall of the pool, spa, or hot tub must be provided." (1) How do I accomplish this if the subpanel is 30' away? (2) How can the pump mfr require this if it's not part of the pool code? (3) A disconnect within 5' of the pool seems pretty excessive considering the pool will be surrounded by a stone patio.

Comment: Longneck:  I will find the liquid tight flexible conduit. Thanks for the tip. Maybe that's what is on my HVAC units.

Comment: @Doug -- you can't use individual wires outside of a raceway or enclosure (see NEC 300.3(A))

Comment: Nate is wrong. The manual says at least 5 feet, not within 5 feet. The breaker in your intermatic panel will satisfy this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Wire from main panel to subpanel is protected by the breaker in the main panel.  So its size is decided by the breaker.

- 30A means 10AWG Cu
- 40A means 8 AWG Cu
- 60A means 6 AWG Cu / 4 AWG Al
- 70A means 4 AWG Cu
- 80A means 3 AWG Al

All these numbers for <100A feeders come out of table 30.15(b)(16) working out of the 60C column because of NEC 110.14(C)(1)(a). Nobody is going to recommend working out of the 90C column, and the inspector is unlikely to approve it.

Additionally, #10 Cu wire will be limited to 30A because of 240.4(D)(7).

---

You are welcome to use  #14 copper wire to lighting or convenience receptacle branch circuits.  It must be breakered at 15A due to 240.4(D)(3).

If you want to breaker it at 20A, then use either #12 copper or #10 aluminum.

Although 240.4(D)(6) allows 25A on #10 aluminum on receptacle branch circuits, use of a breaker other than 15 or 20A is outlawed by Table 210.21(B)(3).

Your expectation of being able to work out of the 90C column is weird.  That's generally not allowed.  Generally in <100A circuits you must work with the abovementioned table, plus

- 15A means 14 AWG Cu.
- 20A means 12 AWG Cu.

---

There is an exception in Code for certain large motor loads on dedicated circuits, which allows an enlarged breaker.  This is to avoid nuisance trips and has nothing to do with wire thermal rating, to which 240.4 still applies.  One of us is an expert on this clause and hopefully will discuss it.   However, using this exception draws a lot of heat from inspectors and you will often need to defend the choice.

However, 110.3(B) still bears force: If the labeling or instructions for the motor, breaker or panel requires the larger wire, you must use it; end of subject!

---

I personally would use EMT conduit for distribution past the subpanel.  I also think use of #14 is a mistake.

As things are, you will need to buy 6 wire sizes and colors:  Black, white and green #12; and black, white and green #14.  **That's six spools, what a waste of money!** I use EMT conduit and would buy only black and white #12. EMT provides the ground. Actually, I own 10 colors of #12 and no #14.  The price difference 12-14 isn't worth it.

---

Lastly, it is far past time to talk about GFCI.  GFCI protecting the pump would not be a bad idea.  The other circuits require it.  You may be reluctant to protect the pump since the cost of all these GFCIs is really stacking up.  However you can protect them all with one GFCI device:  Either

- a GFCI breaker in the main panel that feeds the subpanel (about $90) or
- a "hot tub" subpanel which includes GFCI protection onboard.  Obviously it will need enough *spaces* to support the pump and lighting/recep circuits.  One option is a 2-space "hot tub" subpanel that supports a quadplex breaker.  *(not all brands do)*.

Comment: Note that the equipotential bond *does* need to run to the pump, not the subpanel -- this is required by 680.26(B)(6), and the AHJ *cannot* require you to extend an equipotential bond from the pool to a remote subpanel for that matter (this is also in 680.26(B))

Comment: Thanks TPE.  I wasn't sure about that area of grounding. Still, it seems to me that bonding is slim substitute for GFCI protection.

Comment: I would put GFCI protection on the pump in addition to bonding it; the two work together in this case :)

Comment: Thanks TPE. I will use a GFCI breaker on the pump, too. All three will be GFCIs.

Comment: Harper - for your overarching post - thank you for taking the time to explain and provide references. I'm reading up on them and appreciate your help and the learning lesson. I will switch to a GFCI breaker in the main panel and use non-GFCI breakers in the subpanel. Regarding your EMT suggestion, I assume you mean between the main panel and subpanel? For everything from the subpanel out into the yard, don't I have to use PVC or direct burial cable? EMT is no good buried in the yard?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you'd bury the subpanel-pump and subpanel-outlet connections.  You can use EMT, it just won't last.  Rigid (RMC) will last but it's expensive.

Comment: Two last questions for you all regarding buried cable:    (1) For the 115v convenience receptacle circuit, can I use schedule 40 PVC for everything underground (18" trench) and use schedule 80 for the sections that are above ground (from sub-panel to first 90, and then from last 90 up and out to the receptacle)?     (2) I know I need separate conduit for the low voltage pool light wire, but can I put it in the same trench with the 115v circuit (18" deep)?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, you need to look at the directions for the panel: https://www.intermatic.com/-/media/inriver/11671-10608.ashx/PE20000%20Door%20Label%20Instructions

[image]

Your main panel should have 1 two-pole breaker. Since your pump is 1.65 HP, you need to  use a 50 amp breaker in your main panel to feed the Intermatic panel.

In the Intermatic panel, you will need 3 breakers: pump, 12 V lights, outlet. This panel has an option to hold the 12 V transformer in the panel.

Comment: Longneck:  Thank you. Can you explain how to read the table? It seems like you have the 5HP pump row highlighted. Also thanks for the tip about the transformer - that may save me from finding a place for the transformer out in the yard.

Comment: OP is supplying 240V to the motor.c

Comment: Oops, you're right. I was looking in the 120 V column. Looking at the table, they recommend a 20 amp breaker in the main panel for a 240 V 2 HP pump. I would go larger anyway, probably 30 amp and #10 wire. That gives you headroom to have the pump running at the same time you have a large load on your convenience outlet. If that will never happen, then you can use a 20 amp breaker and #12 wire.

Comment: Longneck and Harper - you guys rock. Thank you both. I edited the post to show a 30A breaker with #10 from the main to the sub-panel. Last question for you guys:  can I use all #14 for the circuits considering the pump and the 120v circuit lengths? I did try to look at the associated tables for that and think it should be okay.

Comment: @doug, if you bump those circuits down to 15A (which is probably fine) then yes, you can use #14 wire.  If you breaker them at 20A you're required to use #12.

Comment: Nate, Longneck and Harper - thank you all. I'll make my final edit which is three 15A breakers and all #14.

Comment: You can't use a 15 amp breaker for the pump. The panel label says 20 amps and #12 wire. Also check the pump. The label may require a 20 amp breaker.

Comment: No, in fact, OP must use a 15A breaker for the pump since the pump's labeling requires it (page 10): https://hayward-pool-assets.com/assets/documents/pools/pdf/manuals/maxflo-vs-IS2303VSP2.pdf?fromCDN=true

Comment: The panel's labeling is only talking about continuous-duty motors, which this pump is not.  So I think it's fine to work out of the general purpose circuit column, and since the pump is labeled to draw a max of 10A, #14 wire on a 15A breaker is fine.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that he mentioned which model pump he's using.

Comment: Again, this is valuable advice and feedback. So here's a hypothetical question:  what happens when I use a 15A breaker and #14 because this pump says to, but then want a larger HP pump in the future. Could I use a 20A breaker and #12 to future proof and in case a larger HP pump is desired in the future? Page 10 does say "Connect pump to a 15 amp branch circuit in accordance with
local codes, regulations, and the National Electric Code (NEC)." Does this mean "must" or can I use 20A and #12. Just asking to learn how to interpret and learn from you guys. I assume I can go bigger. Thanks again.

Comment: I still think running #10 is a good idea, even if you only use 15 amp breaker, for exactly the reason you have stated: future upgrades are likely to need more power.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing not mentioned yet is permits, living in Virginia you're likely going to need to pull permits for all of this and you have to get them before starting anything and get approved, pay all the fees, post the permits, etc. Start on this now because they might be backlogged for weeks or months and you don't want to have to wait on the bureaucracy with all the supplies sitting in the garage.